# Spring Batch is not populating objects when reading XML

Tags: xml, spring-batch, xmlreader

I am trying to read an xml file using Spring Batch so I can parse out certain data and place it in a dat file.  However whenever I try to process the file I get a NullPointerException.  Investigating the reason, it seems that the object I am trying to populate values are being set to null.  It creates a list of the same amount of School tags found in the xml but the values are null.  Below is an example of the xml I am trying to read and the code I am using to populate the object.  What am I doing wrong?

**ItemReader**

```
@Bean
ItemReader<school> underwritingXmlFileItemReader(){     //Environment environment
    StaxEventItemReader<School> xmlFileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();

    xmlFileReader.setResource(editedInput);
    xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("school");
    Jaxb2Marshaller schoolMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    schoolMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(School.class);
    xmlFileReader.setUnmarshaller(schoolMarshaller);    
    return xmlFileReader;
}
```

**School.class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="School", namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Diamond.Business.ThirdParty.School.Adapters.Prelude")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class School {

    @XmlElement(name="SchoolNumber", defaultValue="")
    private String uniqueId;

    @XmlElement(name="Teacher", defaultValue= "")
    private Teacher teacher;

    public String getUniqueId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
    public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }
    public Policyholder getPolicyholder() {
        return policyholder;
    }
    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.policyholder = policyHolder;
    }
}
```

**Teacher.class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Teacher", namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Diamond.Business.ThirdParty.School.Adapters.Prelude")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Teacher {

    @XmlElement(name = "DisplayName", defaultValue="")
    private String fullName;

    @XmlElement(name = "DOB", defaultValue="")
    private String dob;

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

**SchoolList.xml**

```
    <SchoolList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Diamond.Business.ThirdParty.School.Adapters.Prelude">
  <School>
      <Teacher>
        <DOB>1/1/1970</DOB>
        <DisplayName>Ziva Brown</DisplayName>
        <DoingBusinessAs />
        <FirstName>Ziva</FirstName>
        <LastName>Brown</LastName>
        <MiddleName />
      </Teacher>
  </School>
  <School>
     <Teacher>
        <DOB>1/1/1970</DOB>
        <DisplayName>Alex John</DisplayName>
        <DoingBusinessAs />
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>John</LastName>
        <MiddleName />
     </Teacher>
  </School>
</SchoolList>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That doesn't help me out.  What I am trying to figure out is why Spring Batch is leaving the School Object values null instead of populating them.  I think it may have something to do with the xmlns attribute in the SchoolList tag.

Comment: Have you tried setting the namespace in the fragment root element name like:   `xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Diamond.Business.ThirdParty.School.Adapters.Prelude}School");` ? I see the declaration of your reader `StaxEventItemReader<Underwriting> xmlFileReader` and not  `StaxEventItemReader<School> xmlFileReader`. Is that correct? It should be the same return type as the method signature.

Comment: The 'staxEventItemReader<Underwriting> xmlFileReader' is correct.  For this post I had changed some of the names around for security purposes.  I had just missed that one when I did so.  I'll fix that up now.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine.  I got the same exception when I tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is wrapped in `SchoolList` tags

So where is your SchoolList.java?

Comment: I shouldn't need a `SchoolList` object as the as the `xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("school");` tells the reader that the `School` tag is the root element that makes up each separate object.

Answer (score 0):

This processor is looking for the "school" root element name.  There are no such elements in your xml.  Change this:

```
xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("school");
```

to this:

```
xmlFileReader.setFragmentRootElementName("School");
```